# Making IK Bones Look like rings instead of bones

Tags: rigging

Hello I have kind of a stupid question I've never used or made an IK rig before and made one following tutorials I found online, the IK's I created with this look like bones [image]

They work pretty well but I'd like them to look something like this:

[image]

It doesn't really effect me I'd just prefer it to look like these. It wouldn't matter if I figured out how to do this but if somebody could help I'd really apricate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pose mode, in the Bone properties menu and under the viewport display pannel, you can use a custom object to change the shape of the bone. The [bone widget](https://github.com/waylow/boneWidget) addon helps making the worflow faster

[image]